# zend framework urls and get method

Tags: zend-framework, forms, get, submit

I am developing a website using zend framework.

i have a search form with get method. when the user clicks submit button the query string appears in the url after ? mark. but i want it to be zend like url.

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the JS approach you can do a redirect back to the preferred URL you want. I.e. let the form submit via GET, then redirect to the ZF routing style.

This is, however, overkill unless you have a really good reason to want to create neat URLs for your search queries. Generally speaking a search form should send a GET query that can be bookmarked. And there's nothing wrong with ?param=val style parameters in a URL :-)

ZF URLs are a little odd in that they force URL parameters to be part of the main URL. I.e. domain.com/controller/action/param/val/param2/val rather than domain.com/controller/action?param=val&param2=val

This isn't always what you want, but seems to be the way frameworks are going with URL parameters

Comment: +1 While the redirect seems like it should be unnecessary, this seems like the way to go. See my answer with a reusable controller method to get that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no obvious solution. The form generated by zf will be a standard html one. When submitted from the browser using GET it will result in a request like

```
/action/specified/in/form?var1=val1&var2=var2
```

Only solution to get a "zendlike url" (one with / instead of ? or &), would be to hack the form submission using javascript. For example you can listen for onSubmit, abort the submission and instead redirect browser to a translated url. I personally don't believe this solution is worth the added complexity, but it should perform what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

After raging against this for a day-and-a-half, and doing my best to figure out the right way to do this fairly simple this, I gave up and did the following.  I still can't believe there's not a better way.

The use case that necessitates this is a simple record listing, with a form up top for adding some filters (via GET), maybe some column sorting, and Zend_Paginate thrown in for good measure.  I ran into issues using the Url view helper in my pagination partial, but I suspect with even just sorting and a filter-form, Zend_View_Helper_Url would still fall down.

But I digress.  My solution was to add a method to my base controller class that merges any raw query-string parameters with the existing zend-style slashy-params, and redirects (but only if necessary).  The method can be called in any action that doesn't have to handle POSTs.

Hopefully someone will find this useful.  Or even better, find a better way:

```
  /**
   * Translate standard URL parameters (?foo=bar&baz=bork) to zend-style 
   * param (foo/bar/baz/bork).  Query-string style
   * values override existing route-params.
   */
  public function mergeQueryString(){
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
      throw new Exception("mergeQueryString only works on GET requests.");
    }    
    $q = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
    $p = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (empty($q)) {
      //there's nothing to do.
      return;
    }
    $action = $p['action'];
    $controller = $p['controller'];
    $module = $p['module'];
    unset($p['action'],$p['controller'],$p['module']);
    $params = array_merge($p,$q);
    $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')
            ->setCode(301)            
            ->gotoSimple(
                    $action,
                    $controller,
                    $module,
                    $params);

  }
```